# Анимация появления элемента на css3?

Tags: css, css3

как реализовать на плавное появления элемент на страннице
Анимация - с `opacity: 0` в `opacity: 1`

```
.base-box {
    transition: .7s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Анимация появления блока:

```css
.box {
  animation: 5s show ease;
}

@keyframes show {
  from { opacity: 0; }
  to { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">Show Box</div>
```

Или вариант появления блока по наведению:

```css
.box {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.box-wrap:hover .box {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-wrap">
  Hover me:

  <div class="box">Show Box</div>
</div>
```

смотря что нужно.